# cannot access global variable after trying to modify it inside a function

Tags: python, function, variables, scope, local

I encounter no problems running this code:

```
x = 1

def func():
    print(x + 1)

func()
```

```
2
```

But when I run this:

```
x = 1

def func():
    try:
        x += 1
    except:
        pass
    print(x + 1)

func()
```

An error pops:

```
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'x' where it is not associated with a value
```

I am not asking if I can modify global variables in functions or not. I used try-except keywords to avoid that error. After python caught the exception, I thought nothing would change and `print(x + 1)` would work like the first code. So what changed in the scope during the try-except part that x is no longer accessible?

Comment: If you want to assign a new value to a global variable within a function, you must add `global x` as the first statement of the function.  Otherwise, as you see, Python assumes you didn't really want to screw up a global.  BTW, globals are evil.  You should try to avoid them.

Comment: @TimRoberts I know. That's why I used the try-except keywords. I want to know what happens after 'except: pass' that x is no longer accessible inside the function.

Comment: it makes `x` **local**, which causes it to raise an exception, and the assignment to `x` never completes, so when you try to print `x + 1`, the variable is not defined

Comment: @UpTheIrons *the same reason* it wasn't accessible inside the `try: ... `block

Comment: Right.  The MERE FACT that you have `x += 1` in your function makes the name `x` a local throughout the entire function.  Python will no longer look for a global.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you. That was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The first example works because the function does not *assign* to the `x` variable; it only *reads* the variable.

The second example fails because if a function *assigns* to a variable then it is assumed to be a local variable, even if there is a global variable of the same name.

If you want to use the global variable in the function, put `global x` at the top of the function.